# Obtener los primeros 1000 Números primos

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código para hallar los primeros 1000 números primos, no encuentro la forma de escribir un "si y solo si es divisible por 1 y el mismo numero", no se si hay alguna forma pero me gustaría conocerla

```js
function primeNumbers(max){
  var primes = []
  var noPrimes = []

  for (let i = 2; i < max; i++) {
    if (i%i === 0) {
      primes.push(i)
    } else {
      noPrimes.push(i)
    }
  }

  console.log(primes);
  console.log(noPrimes);

}

console.log(primeNumbers(1000))
```

Comment: Pues podrías escribir un ciclo que vaya almacenando en un arreglo dinámico uno por uno los números y que vaya probando cada numero siguiente dividiéndolo por los números que se vayan almacenando en el arreglo aunque esto podría tomar un tiempo; no se me ocurre un forma mas eficiente :'|

Comment: gracias por responder, ya intente lo que dices(el mismo ciclo for va testeando uno a uno los números para "saber si son primos") pero aun no encuentro una manera de hacerlo comprensible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    
    function primeNumbers(max){
        for (let i = 2; i < max; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primes.push(i)
            }
            else{
                noPrimes.push(i)
            }
        }
    }

    function isPrime(n){
        for(let i = 2; i < n; i++){
            if(n % i === 0){
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    var primes = []
    var noPrimes = []

    primeNumbers(50);
    console.log(primes);
    console.log(noPrimes);
```

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por el apoyo en responder, pero te sugiero revisar [answer] eso y además siempre explicar el código que posteas